# Usi del pronome "chi"

Tags: word-usage, grammar, pronouns

Secondo quest'[articolo del Vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/chi1/) il pronome "chi", può avere, come relativo, funzione di soggetto, di oggetto o di complemento di termine, o può persino compiere due funzioni sintattiche diverse dentro della stessa frase. Come pronome interrogativo può avere funzione di soggetto, di predicato o di complemento. Potreste spiegarme tutte queste funzioni di "chi" facendo alcuni esempi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chiedo scusa in anticipo per la poca fantasia delle frasi.

Pronome relativo soggetto:

> **Non ricordo chi me l'ha detto**

Pronome relativo oggetto diretto:

> **Non ricordo chi ho visto ieri**

Pronome relativo complemento di termine:

> **Non ricordo a chi l'ho dato**

Pronome interrogativo soggetto:

> **Chi l'ha detto?**

Pronome interrogativo complemento diretto:

> **Chi hai visto ieri?**

Pronome interrogativo complemento di termine:

> **A chi l'hai dato?**

Come predicato (nominale):

> **Chi sei?**
>
> **Chi credi sia stato?**

Ci sono vari usi che sono permessi o obbligatori in spagnolo e catalano ma non in italiano, per esempio:

> Il mio amico, <s>chi</s> **che** si chiama Marco, è di Milano
>
> Il mio amico, <s>chi</s> **che** anche tu conosci, è di Milano
>
> La persona <s>a chi</s> **[alla quale|a cui]** ho dato il libro, è di Milano

In generale, questi casi si hanno quando il pronome relativo si riferisce a una persona precedentemente menzionata.